# Filter a query using value of XElement within XML using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

Using LINQ C#, I am querying a database table. The table has a column which contains XML and I would like to filter the results based on an element's value inside the XML being equal to a predefined string. I am using the following query:

```
(from data in DataObjects.Items
where data.DataItemTimeUtc < DateTime.UtcNow && 
data.DataItemXml.XDocument
   .Descendants("Items")
   .Descendants("MetaData")
   .Descendants("Device")
   .First().Value == "abc123"
orderby data.DataItemTimeUtc descending
select data).ToArray();
```

but it is failing with an error:

> *The expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]'
>   is not a sequence*

Comment: There's a syntax error, there should be a leading ( before "from" to match the parenthesis after "select data".

Comment: Is the .XDocument property something that Entity Framework generates? I haven't tried querying into an Xml column - looks very cool if it's possible!

Comment: @neontapir: thanks. fixed the syntax now.

Comment: @CodingInsomnia: It is not something the Entity Framework generates. I am converting the property in my data class to an XmlString

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var x = DataObjects.Items
 .Where(data => data.DataItemTimeUtc < DateTime.UtcNow
 && data.DataItemXml.XDocument
  .Elements("Items")
  .Elements("MetaData")
  .Elements("Device")
  .First().Value == "abc123")
 .OrderBy(data => data.DataItemTimeUtc);
```

I've just tried to remove your syntax errors, changed `Descendants` to `Elements` which takes only immediate children. Then I changed it to Method Syntax instead of Expression Syntax to keep things together that belong together. You have to be aware though that the `.First()` might not result any element and then the `.Value` will throw a null reference exception.